# Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`) in JAX-RS PUT Endpoint

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'm getting an error that no matter what I try doesn't seem to get fixed. In my eyes everything looks correct. This is my service for the endpoint

```
@PUT
    @Path("/{bookId}")
    public Response editBook(@PathParam("bookId") Long bookId, Book newBook) {
        
        
        if (!JWTTokenAuth.validateJwtToken(JWTTokenAuth.extractTokenFromHeaders(headers))) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }

        Book book = bookDao.getBookById(bookId);
        if (book == null) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }

        book.setTitle(newBook.getTitle());

        bookDao.updateBook(book);

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

And this is my entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String title;
    private String author;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<Review> reviews;

}
```

When I try to hit the endpoint through postman (for example) http://localhost:8080/api/books/2

with the authorization setup correctly and my JSON payload set as this

```
{
    "title": "defgefgege"
}
```

I get this error and I think it has to do with the PathParam?
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
at [Source: (io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl); line: 1, column: 1
]

Comment: I don't think it's the PathParam. I think it's looking for `Long id` in `Book`.

Comment: @DavidConrad I had the parameter as query param before and it worked fine with the same payload. So I'm pretty sure it's the PathParam's fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue, which was that I was receiving an empty path parameter.

I had imported PathParam from `jakarta.websocket.server.PathParam;`
While it should have been from `jakarta.ws.rs.PathParam;`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is not in your Java code but in PostMan. Have you mist-typed the parameter in the URL or forgot to set it?

My guess is that PostMan is not sending this URL:

`http://localhost:8080/api/books/2`

but

`http://localhost:8080/api/books/{bookID}`

That would explain the error message you are seeing.